# emails with double quotes regex or validation function

Tags: regex, validation, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I am facing a really challenging Regex here, due to strict requirements

I need to create a regex or a validation function that enables me to:

- User will input this in text field:

  ```
  xxxx”aaaa\”bbbbb\”ccccccc\”ddddd\”eeeeee”yyyyy”ffffff\”ggggg\”hhhh\”iiiii\”jjjj”wwww
  ```
- I need to get all double quoted string inside this big string, i need to get it full.    ( in this case :

  ```
  ”aaaa\”bbbbb\”ccccccc\”ddddd\”eeeeee”
  and
  ”ffffff\”ggggg\”hhhh\”iiiii\”jjjj” )
  ```
- Then I need to check if all quotes are escaped correctly and if some defined chars are being used

  ```
  (
    e.g. tis pattern  
  [a-zA-Z0-9!#\$%&'\*\+-/=\?\^_`\{|\}~"\(\),:;<>@\[\\\]] 
  )
  ```

  The problem I am facing is that escaped quotes are being escaped. And then
- In the first step it is returning me … a list of 6 values

  ```
  ”aaaa” , ”ccccccc ”, ”eeeeee”,”ffffff”, “hhhh”, ”jjjj”
  ```

That is not that I need. Any ideas on this?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Maybe this won't help at all but I did make [this regex](http://regex101.com/r/gT2nQ3/1) that **might** be able to work (somewhat) for you. It's mostly just something that interested me.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good example to use negative lookbehind, you can use this regex to get the content you want:

```
”.*?(?<!\\)”
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/fB6dP2/1)**

Using capturing groups you can grab those strings:

```
(”.*?(?<!\\)”)
```

[image]

Here is the matches

```
MATCH 1
1.  [4-41]  `”aaaa\”bbbbb\”ccccccc\”ddddd\”eeeeee”`
MATCH 2
1.  [46-80] `”ffffff\”ggggg\”hhhh\”iiiii\”jjjj”`
```

Then you can apply the logic you want on this strings.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Javascript, which doesn't support lookbehinds as [Fede](https://stackoverflow.com/users/710099/fede) suggested, then this is what you want:

```
(".+?(?:[^\\]"))
```

[RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/tU9cP9/1)

Explanation:

- `(` Capturing Group

  - `".+?` A quote, followed by any number of characters
  - `(?:` Non-capturing group

    - `[^\\]"` A quote not preceded by a backslash
  - `)` End non-capturing group
- `)` End capturing group